# isql error: Could not sql connect in Zabbix appliance

Tags: sql-server, odbc, zabbix

I want to monitor the data in a Microsoft SQL Server database using Zabbix by ODBC and without agent. I have installed ODBC on Zabbix appliance (VMware).

When I enter command `isql test`, I get error:

> Could not SQL connect.

Also in Zabbix front dashboard there is a problem: SQL Server could not fetch info data. The settings of my odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini files are as below:

odbc.ini:

```
[mssql]
Description: mssql database connected to zabbix
Driver= ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Server= the ip of database server 
User= my username in database server
Password= my password in database server
Port= 1433
Database= database name
```

odbcinst.ini:

```
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description= Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver = /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.7.so.2.1
```

Comment: Is the SQL Server instance actually listening on port 1433? That's only the default port, it could be listening on different port - especially if it is a named instance. Is it accessible via network firewalls and Windows Firewall on the host? If you can't get a Simple Check using `net.tcp.service[tcp,your-server-ip-address,1433]` (again, that's the default port) to connect from the Zabbix appliance then ODBC won't be able to connect either.

Answer (score 0):

You should use verbose mode :

> -v     Turn on the verbose mode, where the errors are fully described. Useful for debugging.

And specify the DSN you want to connect to:

```
isql –v your_DSN
```

This should be enough to pinpoint the cause of the connection error.

Comment: I did it, and the result is:                                                                                            [UnixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]login failed for user ''.

Comment: Seems that the DSN definiztion is incorrect, isql cannot get the username

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

```
[ZPRX-UAT ~]$ isql mssqltest -v
[28000][unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user ''.
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

In my case it helped to remove the user and password in the /etc/odbc.ini file.
Then, using the isql command with the -v parameter and a user with a password. The isql command ended correctly in my case.

```
[ZPRX-UAT ~]$ isql -v mssqltest Test Test123
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
SQL>
```